# Export matrices generated in C++ (using Armadillo) to .mat files

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

I have the C++ code below (which is compiled using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) library) and I want to export the created matrix to a **.mat** file to be later imported in MATLAB. I searched already in Google but I did not find any solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(){

int ny,nx,nz;
ny = 2;
nx = 2;
nz = 4;

cube A(ny,nx,nz,fill::zeros);

int s;

for (s = 0; s < nz; s++){

    A.slice(s) = (s+1) * ones<mat>(ny,nx);   

}

return 0;}
```

Any Idea of how to store **A** into a **.mat** file?

Ps.: OS = Windows 10

Comment: Try the [matio](https://sourceforge.net/projects/matio/) library.

Comment: You can also directly [save](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_mat) it in HDF5 format. Matlab has support for loading HDF5 files.